# Redux: organising containers, components, actions and reducers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, architecture, redux, flux

***The question:***

> What is the most maintainable and recommended best practice for organising containers, components, actions and reducers in a large
>   [React/Redux](https://github.com/reactjs) application?

***My opinion:***

Current trends seem to organise redux collaterals (actions, reducers, sagas...) around the associated container component. e.g.

```
/src
    /components
        /...
    /contianers
        /BookList
            actions.js
            constants.js
            reducer.js
            selectors.js
            sagas.js
            index.js
        /BookSingle
            actions.js
            constants.js
            reducer.js
            selectors.js
            sagas.js
            index.js        
    app.js
    routes.js
```

This works great! Although there seems to be a couple of issues with this design.

***The Issues:***

When we need to access `actions`, `selectors` or `sagas` from another container it seems an anti-pattern. Let's say we have a global `/App` container with a reducer/state that stores information we use over the entire app such as categories and enumerables. Following on from the example above, with a state tree:

```
{
    app: {
        taxonomies: {
            genres: [genre, genre, genre],
            year: [year, year, year],
            subject: [subject,subject,subject],
        }   
    }
    books: {
        entities: {
            books: [book, book, book, book],
            chapters: [chapter, chapter, chapter],
            authors: [author,author,author],
        }
    },
    book: {
        entities: {
            book: book,
            chapters: [chapter, chapter, chapter],
            author: author,
        }
    },
}
```

If we want to use a `selector` from the `/App` container within our `/BookList` container we need to either recreate it in `/BookList/selectors.js` (surely wrong?) OR import it from `/App/selectors` (will it always be the EXACT same selector..? no.). Both these appraoches seem sub-optimal to me.

The prime example of this use case is Authentication (ah... auth we do love to hate you) as it is a *VERY* common "side-effect" model. We often need to access `/Auth` sagas, actions and selectors all over the app. We may have the containers `/PasswordRecover`, `/PasswordReset`, `/Login`, `/Signup` .... Actually in our app our `/Auth` contianer has no actual component at all!

```
/src
    /contianers
        /Auth
            actions.js
            constants.js
            reducer.js
            selectors.js
            sagas.js
```

Simply containing all the Redux collaterals for the various and often un-related auth containers mentioned above.

Comment: I am curious, with your current structure how are you using your selector? Say a component uses `BookList` selectors functions, can you show me your `mapStateToProps` function? are you passing the `state` through? or the `state.booklist`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I personally use the [ducks-modular-redux](https://github.com/erikras/ducks-modular-redux) proposal.

It's not the "official" recommended way but it works great for me. Each "duck" contains a `actionTypes.js`, `actionCreators.js`, `reducers.js`, `sagas.js` and `selectors.js` files. There is no dependency to other ducks in these files to avoid cyclic dependency or [duck circle](https://github.com/erikras/ducks-modular-redux/issues/24#issuecomment-187726770), each "duck" contains only the logic that it have to managed.

Then, at the root I have a `components` and a `containers` folders and some root files :

**`components/`** folder contains all the pure components of my app

**`containers/`** folder contains containers created from pure components above. When a container need a specific `selector` involving many "ducks", I write it in the same file where I wrote the `<Container/>` component since it is relative to this specific container. If the `selector` is shared accros multiple containers, I create it in a separate file (or in a HoC that provides these props).

**`rootReducers.js`** : simply exposes the root reducers by combining all reducers

**`rootSelectors.js`** exposes the root selector for each slice of state, for example in your case you could have something like :

```
/* let's consider this state shape

state = {
    books: {
        items: {  // id ordered book items
            ...
        }
    },
    taxonomies: {
        items: {  // id ordered taxonomy items
            ...
        }
    }
}

*/
export const getBooksRoot = (state) => state.books

export const getTaxonomiesRoot = (state) => state.taxonomies
```

It let us "hide" the state shape inside each ducks `selectors.js` file. Since each `selector` receive the whole state inside your ducks you simply have to import the corresponding `rootSelector` inside your `selector.js` files.

**`rootSagas.js`** compose all the sagas inside your ducks **and** manage complex flow involving many "ducks".

So in your case, the structure could be :

```
components/
containers/
ducks/
    Books/
        actionTypes.js
        actionCreators.js
        reducers.js
        selectors.js
        sagas.js
    Taxonomies/
        actionTypes.js
        actionCreators.js
        reducers.js
        selectors.js
        sagas.js
rootSelectors.js
rootReducers.js
rootSagas.js
```

When my "ducks" are small enough, I often skip the folder creation and directly write a `ducks/Books.js` or a `ducks/Taxonomies.js` file with all these 5 files (`actionTypes.js`, `actionCreators.js`, `reducers.js`, `selectors.js`, `sagas.js`) merged together.